# PHP extensions path in ubuntu

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I want to install a php package in ubuntu. that package need to php mongo extension and i installed and i put in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` :

```
extension=mongo.so
```

But i got an error to install that package :

```
the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
```

So when I want to know where is the mongo extension i typing `php -i | grep extension_dir` shows :

```
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php5/20131226 => /usr/lib/php5/20131226
```

And when typing `php-config --extension-dir` shows :

```
/usr/lib/php5/20121212
```

I think extensions path is wrong but i dont know, how can i fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `sudo apt-get install php5-mongo` you will have it working.
hope it helps :)

Comment: this worked for me, did you make sure to restart the web server? i.e. `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 1):

Install your mongo.so in your lampp

/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/

Keep this path in your

/opt/lampp/lib/php/php.ini file

extension=mongo.so

Comment: i do not use lampp

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mongo
```

if that doesnt work try these
sudo apt-get install php5-dev make php-pear
sudo pecl install mongo
sudo echo "extension=mongo.so" | sudo tee /etc/php5/mods-available/mongo.ini

Comment: i got error to install php5-dev :  `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-dev : Depends: libpcre3-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: pkg-php-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`

Comment: Alright try this...
** $ sudo apt-get -f install  **
**$ sudo apt-get install php**                                         
and hit TAB key on your keyboard a few times, which should give you something like this                                
 Display all 492 possibilities? (y or n)                   
Then go ahead and hit 'y' you would see all the possible values